# Steam refuses to update/run on my computer

Tags: windows-7, windows, steam

I have just installed Steam on my computer. However, whenever I try to update it (first time use), it just displays the update window, sits at 0% and then vanishes a couple of seconds later. I did an uninstall/re-install and re-downloaded the installer and did the same thing, but these don't work. I'm sure Steam never updates at all since it refuses to run, and just keep displaying the update window when I try to launch Steam.

I use Windows 7 Professional 32-bit on MacBook 13-inch dual-boot.

Comment: Are you using an administrator account?

Comment: Yes, I am using an administrator account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh wait, I've just woke up and logged in to my system. It had completed a Windows Update over the night and apparently Steam now works. I guess that means, its problem solved. I wonder if it's due to the update, but may be, since restarting the computer initially didn't help. But anyway, it's fixed. Thanks all.

Comment: Steam is great but it constantly is quirky. Next time you have a problem, don't jump the gun. It'll start working again. This happens to me all the time.

Also, consider asking your question at https://support.steampowered.com/

Comment: Okay. Well, I was recommended by one of my friends (who is a user on one of these projects) to post here, so I chose to. I also tried to do a Google search for my problem, but I drew a blank on that.

Answer (score 1):

Go into the Steam folder at c:/program files/steam and delete the .blob files. AppUpdateStats.blob and ClientRegistry.blob. That'll force steam to re-download the client from scratch rather than updating it.

If that isn't the issue, I would try looking if you are able to ping steam network servers and/or check if you have the right frameworks installed.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a firewall installed on your computer make sure it's not blocking Steam.

Also make sure there are no firewalls on your network. If there are, try updating Steam from another place.

By the way, you do know Valve released a Steam version for Mac OS X, right? It's decent! It runs Counter-Strike Source and all of that.

Comment: My Windows side was freshly installed, so it's devoid of a lot of the usual software. I don't have 3rd party anti-virus or firewalls. I have Windows Firewall activated, though. 

I dislike playing on Mac, because the mouse motion is quite terrible. Loads of mouse acceleration, very different from Windows.